# How can I print a datetime in the xs:dateTime format in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, datetime

I would like to take a time stamp (e.g. 1263531246) and convert it to a string representation suitable for output to an XML file in an attribute field conforming to `xs:dateTime`. `xs:dateTime` expects something like:

`2002-05-30T09:30:10-06:00`

Ideally, I would use the form of output that includes offset from UTC (as above).  In this project, I am constrained to use Perl.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works on Linux:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -e 'print POSIX::strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z\n", localtime)'
2010-02-04T17:37:43-0500
```

On Windows, with ActiveState Perl, it prints:

```
2010-02-04T17:39:24Eastern Standard Time
```

Using [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

use DateTime;
my $dt = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'EST');
print $dt->strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'), "\n"
```

I get the correct string on Windows as well:

```
E:\> t
2010-02-04T18:06:24-0500
```

I believe [Date::Format](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Date::Format) is much lighter weight module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

use Date::Format;
print time2str('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z', time, 'EST'), "\n";
```

Output:

```
E:\> t
2010-02-04T18:11:36-0500
```

Answer (score 8):

Using the right [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime) formatting module,  you can translate between
formatted strings and DateTime objects without writing any painful regexes to parse or using `strftime()` to format.

You seem to need the XSD format (a subset of ISO8601, used in XML schemas): see [DateTime::Format::XSD](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime::Format::XSD).

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::XSD;

my $dt = DateTime->now;
print DateTime::Format::XSD->format_datetime($dt);
```

produces:

```
2010-02-04T23:24:11+00:00
```

If you are processing lots of DateTime objects, you could shorten your code by relying on automatic formatting and stringification; simply pass the 'formatter' argument to your DateTime constructor:

```
my $dt = DateTime->new(year => 1999, month => 1, day => 1,
                       formatter => 'DateTime::Format::XSD'
                      );

my $xml = "<date>$dt</date>";   # through the magic of overloading, this works!
```

results in:

```
<date>1999-01-01T00:00:00+00:00</date>
```

For more information, see http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/lib/DateTime.pm#Formatters_And_Stringification.